# Display current user's profile picture in <lightning:fileCard fileId=""

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, images, user-profile

I'm currently retrieving the current user's profile picture with the SOQL query:

```
String image = [SELECT Id, isProfilePhotoActive, MediumPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()][0].MediumPhotoUrl];
```

In a Lightning component, I would like to display this image in a `<lightning:fileCard fileId="{!v.fileId}"` component
(There is therefore need to have a file id and not a url

I think it would need the value of the `ContentDocumentId`

I did `[SELECT Id, linkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE linkedEntityId = UserInfo.getUserId()]`

but `ContentDocumentId` does not contain user profile picture

Would you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user profile (or banner) picture is not stored as a ContentDocument - it's under [Photo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_pictures.htm) which you can tell by the prefix of the Id you do see in those fields you identify (729). The derived fields on [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) show the URL to the image

- FullPhotoUrl
- SmallPhotoUrl
- BannerPhotoUrl
- MediumBannerPhotoUrl
- SmallBannerPhotoUrl

As such, you won't be able to display it with [File Card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/specification) that only accepts a ContentDocument Id.

I presume you want to use File Card to allow users to preview and/or upload new profile pics  - you'll have to handle this separately since you can't use the standard component.

- You can display the preview of the existing profile picture by using the `img` tag.
- If you provide a [file upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) component, you can then use provided classes/methods from Connect API to update photos for users - [UserProfiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_UserProfiles_static_methods.htm).

For displaying the existing photo, you can just use the fields you're already querying. Assuming you store the user object in an attribute, the following will display the image

```
<img src="{!v.user.MediumPhotoURL}"/>
```

Then, in [fileUpload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) component - you use the User Id for the `recordId`

```html
<lightning:fileUpload
    name="fileUploader"
    recordId="{!v.user.Id}"
    onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
```

The component provides an `onuploadfinished` event that you can use to query the relevant details of the uploaded ContentDocument to set as the user photo

```js
({ 
    handleUploadFinished: function (component, event) {
        //get files uploaded (this'll just be one in your scenario)
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        //call apex to set the user photo
        var action = component.get("c.setUserPhoto");
        action.setParams({contentDocumentId : uploadedFiles[0].documentId});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //do whatever logic           
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                //display to user
            } else {
        
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

In your apex, you'd leverage ConnectApi to update the user photo based on the uploaded content document.

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void setUserPhoto(String contentDocumentId){
    ContentVersion contentVersion = [SELECT Id, VersionData, FileType, Title 
                                     FROM ContentVersion  
                                     WHERE ContentDocumentId =: contentDocumentId 
                                     LIMIT 1
                                    ];
 
    String lowerCaseFileType = contentVersion.FileType.toLowerCase();
    ConnectApi.UserProfiles.setPhoto(null, UserInfo.getUserId(), new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(contentVersion.VersionData,'image/' + lowerCaseFileType , contentVersion.Title + '.' + lowerCaseFileType));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect example, but this is how I displayed a user's profile image based on related data on a visualforce page on a case.

This is based on `Case.ContactId.A` User Lookup field on the contact.

The image is medium sized and then in a circle crop style like on user profile pages.

I also ensured Visualforce page was 'Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app' and created a permission set for my users to be able to view the VF page.

This is a preview: [image: Case page layout with profile image of case requestor contact showing at top, along with their name and title]

```
    <apex:page standardController="Case">
    <br />
    <style>
.roundImg{
width: 125px;
height: 125px;
border-radius: 50%;
max-width: none;
}
</style><center>
<apex:image value="{!Case.Account.Salesforce_user__r.mediumPhotoUrl}" styleclass="roundImg" alt="User profile image"/> <br></br><br></br>
<font size="3">  {!Case.Account.Salesforce_user__r.Name}<br></br>
    {!Case.Account.Salesforce_user__r.Title}
    <br></br>
    {!Case.Account.Salesforce_user__r.Acquisition_Company__c} </font>


    </center>
</apex:page>
```